# FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream hang up and fails.

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, ftpwebrequest

I have wrote a web service, in a nutshell it uses openpop to get email messages does stuff with the content to insert into databases and saves attachments which are images. That works fine when i save images locally, it does exactley what it is suppose to. Now an added requirment was to save images to an FTP directory, so i can create my folders dynamically (they are created based upon timestamp) and that works well. My problem comes from when i try to save them to the ftp. Yes my user name and password are correct, otherwise i wouldn't be creating the directory.

```
Private Sub UploadFile(ByVal fileToSave As FileInfo, ByVal path As String)
    Dim UploadRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://UserName:Passowrd@999.99.999.9" & path), FtpWebRequest)
    UploadRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("PicService", "grean.matching18")
    UploadRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
    UploadRequest.UseBinary = True
    UploadRequest.UsePassive = True

    ' Const BufferSize As Integer = 2048
    ' Dim content(BufferSize - 1) As Byte, dataRead As Integer
    Dim bFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToSave.ToString)
    'UploadRequest.ContentLength = content.Length

    Using FileStream1 As FileStream = fileToSave.OpenRead()
        Try
            'open request to send
            Using RequestStream As Stream = UploadRequest.GetRequestStream

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            'ensure file closed
            FileStream1.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

I have tried using Passive False and Binary False as well, i did more research on my stack trace.
And found [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/58df3c3c-1f04-43f2-96e2-3ea1f6698b4f/) but no solution as of yet. Any input would be appreciated, i am also [posting another question on windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880314/windows-services-permission-problems) for different issue. If you would like to take a shot at it, the other question isnt about ftp but permissions for a service on windows server 2003

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles across this... I had the same issue but when I changed to UsePassive = True, it sorted out my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the solution but I've found that the URI string has to be 'just right' and that what is 'just right' varies by the ftp server.

So `ftp://server/directory/file` works on some servers but needs to be `ftp://server//directory/file` to work on others (note the double slash after the server name)

Aso, your URI has 'password' spelled incorrectly: `ftp://UserName:Passowrd@999.99.999.9` and you are supplying the credentials in a separate code line as well.

Comment: your absolutely right, but i did get my credentials working for this. I believe i just changed that for example purposes. I finally was sending the file but i was getting 0 bytes on the other end. I set break points and the file was being converted to bytes but fails to be sent complete to the ftp server.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice i never accepted your answer. I ended up getting credentials to work but through all the routers and switches something happened and i ended up with a 0 byte file on the other side. The second set of credentials overrode the first, so it wasn't the misspelling. I think i was just trying things out. I was creating folders on the directory i was creating the file as well but when my code tried to transfer the bytes across the wire it ended up with a 0 byte file on the other end. It was named right though, lol.